# True/False question about simmetrical bilinear forms

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space of dimension $n$ equipped with a symmetrical bilinear form. If for every subspace $W \not= {0}$ of $V$, $\dim W^{\perp} > \dim V - \dim W$ then the bilinear form $\phi$ is $\phi = 0$. 
Is that true?
Any thoughts? It was an exercise in one of the past papers of my professor, but I can't get my head around it.

Comment: $\dim W^\perp+\dim W = \dim V$ in finite dimensioned $V$, so there must be an error somewhere.

Comment: Isn't that true only if the scalar product is not degenerated?

Comment: @DSquare in this case it's not a scalar product, it's just a bilinear form (sesquilinear in vector spaces over $\Bbb C$).

Comment: @GennaroMarcoDevincenzis : scalar product is not degenerated by definition (cf. wiki, for example).

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry; I forgot to add the definition of scalar product I'm using. I'm considering every simmetrical bilinear form as a scalar product.

Comment: @GennaroMarcoDevincenzis I think calling any symmetrical bilinear form a `scalar product` will confuse a lot of people.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy this is the most common definition of scalar product in Italy, and I honestly thought it was so everywhere. For the sake of clarity, I'm changing it.

Comment: I see your point. When standard local notations clash with international ones, there's always a lot of confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I solved it. (I realise it is pretty dumb to answer your own question, but whatever; it may work even to check if my reasoning is right). Now, let's call $n $ the dimension of $V$. Let $B = {v_{1},...,v_{n}}$ be a base of $V$. If $B$ is a base, then every vector $v\neq0$ (in case $v=0$ the claim is trivial) can be written as a linear combination of the elements of the base. 
$$v = {a_{1}v_{1} +...+ a_{n}v_{n}}$$ 
Now let $W=span(v)$. This subspace has obviously dimension 1. Our hypothesis says that $\dim W^{\perp} > \dim V - \dim W$ so $\dim W^{\perp}=n$. But then $W^{\perp}=V$. So the claim is true.

Comment: You should add $v\ne0$, but otherwise you nailed it.

Comment: thank you very much for the feedback.

Comment: It is not "pretty dumb to answer your own question". Don't forget to accept it as well.

Comment: can't do it until tomorrow. will do anyway. :P